# Formal verification of function contract?

Tags: logic, formal-systems

How could I formally reason about the following function:

```
function f(x){
    if(x>=0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

The statement I'd like to prove is
`\forall x: f(x)!=2`

How can I do it meticulously, using Hoare logic? My main concern is how to prevent the consecutive `return` to overwrite the previous, so what axiom to use to not to be able to do that.

In [this](http://ticki.github.io/blog/a-hoare-logic-for-rust/) blog the writer defines the function call as [image]

This is good to reason about return values, but I don't see how it could be useful.